# Mysql. Query of a detail table relating with two master tables, in an exclusive way

Tags: mysql, sql

A table 'Detail' is related with two 'Master' tables by two fields, foreign keys, in an exclusive way. Either with Master1_ID or Master2_ID (only one of it will have the value of the id of the Maestro table to which it is related, the other will be NULL).

I want to get in a MySQL query the Detail records joined to the corresponding master.

**Tables:**

```
Detail[DetailID, DetailTitle, Master1_ID, Master2_ID, ...]
Master1[MasterID, MasterTitle, ...]
Master2[MasterID, MasterTitle, ...]
```

Master1_ID is the foreign key of the table Master1 and Master2_ID the foreign key of the table Master2. Only one of the two fields will have a value from the table it corresponds to.

**And these are the records of the query I want to get:**

Query: `[DetailID, DetailTitle, MasterID, MasterTitle]`

It will be appreciated to have in mind performance issues.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where are you coming from, if I may ask? Usually you would move from the 'MasterTable' to the DetailTable and not the other way around, meaning you already know which table you need and, subsequently, which column to query.

Comment: Refugnic Eternium, It is not a query for specific values. It is to get each detail record joined with the corresponding master record.

Comment: Please note that this is completely untested and I have no idea if it will work:
`SELECT * FROM Detail LEFT JOIN IF(Master1_ID != NULL, Master1 ON MasterID = Master1_ID, Master2 ON MasterID = Master2_ID);`

Comment: I have been doing tests and I am afraid that an IF statement cannot be used to select the table in the LEFT JOIN part

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables; that may be more precise than vague words like "master" and "detail".

Comment: It is not a vague specification. 'Master' (two masters here) and 'Detail' tables represent a scenario, it is a generic case, so other users can adapt it to their particular case. Is it necessary to know the specific type of a field or something else about the structure to program the needed query? I think not, as you can see from the proposed answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use left join and coalesce

```
SELECT d.DetailID, 
  d.DetailTitle, 
  COALESCE(m1.MasterID,m2.MasterID), 
  COALESCE(m1.MasterTitle,m2.MasterTitle)
FROM Detail d
LEFT JOIN Master1 m1 ON d.Master1_ID = m1.ID 
LEFT JOIN Master2 m2 ON d.Master2_ID = m2.ID
```

Comment: I think ```LEFT JOIN``` is faster in execution than ```UNION```. Although the ```COALESCE()``` function to apply on each field of the master tables is not pretty to look at. (You have my vote)

Answer (score 0):

For now, and if no one has a better idea, **I think the solution is to use the UNION TABLES**:

```
SELECT d.DetailID, d.DetailTitle, m1.MasterID, m1.MasterTitle FROM Detail d, Master1 m1
WHERE d.Master1_ID = m1.ID AND d.Master1_ID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT d.DetailID, d.DetailTitle, m2.MasterID, m2.MasterTitle FROM Detail d, Master2 m2
WHERE d.Master2_ID = m2.ID AND d.Master2_ID IS NOT NULL
```

I leave the question open in case someone can contribute something more.